# How to smoothen edges found in a image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

How to smoothen two line in below image using matlab ? So that it will look like 2 smooth curves.

[image: Edge]

I have try using imdilate and imclose functon as below

```
 imdilate(im_edge,strel('disk', 2))
 imclose(im_edge,strel('square', 2))
```

But edges just become delate or pixels become closer

Comment: Have you tried using a filter? Please show us what you tried.

Comment: How to use a filter to do this, Could you guide me

Comment: You can start by searching the matlab documentation for "filter image"

Comment: i tried with this one [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/integralfilter.html) and it just blur then image and resize the image aswell

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean with *smoothen*. Your question is not really clear enough. Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried already and add the missing details.

Comment: Are there anyway to make edge look like 2 smooth curves ?

Comment: The image is too low quality to allow us see the pixels and local details. Can't answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to find a way to make it look like a curve.
I think using morphological operations in the right directions.
Example for morphological operations:

dilate:

```
I = imread('Rx1wSm.jpg');
se = strel('disk',3);
J = imdilate(I, se);
```

[image]

close:

```
se = strel('disk',3);
J = imclose(I, se);
```

[image]

close with threshold:

```
se = strel('disk',3);
J = imclose(I, se);
J(J > 50) = 255;
J(J<50)=0;
```

[image]

There are many more morphological operations supported by Matlab.
Type `doc bwmorph` in Matlab command windows to view documentation.

There is still a room for improvement, but you need to find a better expert.

Comment: I want to make it look like a curve

Comment: @Le Truong Sinh There are many more morphological operations supported by Matlab. Type `doc bwmorph` in Matlab command windows to view documentation.